# MySql table do not has primary key, django orm can not use

Tags: mysql, django, primary-key

I use Django ORM with a MySQL database, but I have some tables that do not has a primary key. It throws an exception like this:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'XXX.id' in 'field list'")
```

What can I do to fix the exception without modifying my table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't have a model without a primary key.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

> Each model requires exactly one field to have `primary_key=True` (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

Comment: OK..., thank you for your answer, i just fake a column as primary key, but i don't understand why django orm can not support a table without primay key!

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make much sense when working with a legacy database. The only downside is that your `.get` queries won't work (unless that fake PK is actually unique).